# D3 treemap update - not all elements being removed

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a v5 D3 treemap where when I click into a box I'd like it to drill down to the next level - as part of that elements that are not part of that new hierarchy should be removed.  It is mostly working, but not all elements are being removed for some reason.

In the example below if you click on the B1 box you will see that there are extra boxes showing.

Here is an example:

```js
const data = {
 "name": "A1",
 "health": 0.521,
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "B1",
   "health": 0.521,
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "B1-C1",
     "health": 0.614,
     "children": [
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D1",
        "health": 0.666,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E1",
            "value": 30,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E2",
            "value": 35,
            "health": 0.5
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D1-E3",
            "value": 20,
            "health": 0.7
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D2",
        "health": 0.45,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
            "value": 10,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D2-E1",
            "value": 14,
            "health": 0.1
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "B1-C1-D3",
        "health": 0.64,
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E1",
            "value": 10,
            "health": 0.8
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E2",
            "value": 14,
            "health": 0.2
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E3",
            "value": 7,
            "health": 0.7
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E4",
            "value": 9,
            "health": 0.9
          },
          {
            "name": "B1-C1-D3-E5",
            "value": 5,
            "health": 0.6
          }
        ]
      },
      {"name": "B1-C1-D4",
       "value": 2,
       "health": 0.7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
   "name": "B1-C2",
   "health": 0.45,
   "children": [
    {"name": "B1-C2-D1",
     "health": 0.45,
     "value": 12}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "B1-C3",
   "health": 0.5,
   "children": [
    {"name": "B1-C3-D1",
     "health": 0.5,
     "value": 10}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
]
}

const treemapLayout = d3.treemap()
  .size([500, 300])
  .paddingOuter(16);
  
let t = d3.transition().duration(1500)

// update the view
  let update = (d) => {
    console.log(d)

    let rootNode = d3.hierarchy(d)



    rootNode
      .sum(function(d) {
        return d.value;
      })
      .sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.height - a.height || b.value - a.value;
      });


    //console.log(rootNode)

    treemapLayout(rootNode);


    let nodes = d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(rootNode.descendants())

    nodes
      .exit()
      .attr("fill-opacity", 1)
      .transition(t)
      .attr("fill-opacity", 0)
      .remove()

    nodes = nodes
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .merge(nodes)
      .filter(function(d) {
        return d.depth < 4;
      })
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + [d.x0, d.y0] + ')'
    })


    nodes
      .append('rect')
      .attr('width', function(d) {
        return d.x1 - d.x0;
      })
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d.y1 - d.y0;
      })
      .attr('style', function(d) {
        return ('fill:' + d3.interpolateRdYlGn(d.data.health))
      })
      .on('click', function(d) {
        update(d.data);
      })
      .transition(t)


    nodes
      .append('text')
      .attr('dx', 4)
      .attr('dy', 14)
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.data.name;
      })

  };

  update(data);
```

```css
rect {
  fill: cadetblue;
  opacity: 1;
  stroke: white;
}
text {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  fill: #484848;
  font-size: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<svg width="1000" height="800">
  <g></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Just some additional detail on this - it looks like the nodes that are not being removed are the previous parents and grandparents of the new rootNode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the implementation is that you do not identify the nodes using an unique identifier such as an id or the name in your case.

Changing the code to (see code below) will allow D3 to identify the actual nodes correctly when merging

```
  let nodes = d3.select('svg')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(rootNode.descendants(), d => d ? d.name : 'root')
```